# Cannot build opencv WinRT

Tags: opencv, windows-runtime, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV for WinRT by following the instruction [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/platforms/winrt)

1. Opened Visual Studio 2013 developer command prompt, navigated to

   ```
     cd path/opencv/platforms/winrt
   ```

then run the command

```
 setup_winrt.bat "WP,WS" "8.0,8.1" "x86,ARM" -b
```

But which ended up with the following error,

```
INFO>     Directory: E:\Software\OpenCV\opencv_winrt\opencv-master\bin\WP\8.0\x
6
INFO>     Platform: WindowsPhone
INFO>     Version: 8.0
INFO>     Architecture: x86
INFO>     Generator: Visual Studio 12 2013
INFO>     Install Directory: E:\Software\OpenCV\opencv_winrt\opencv-master\bin\
nstall\WP\8.0\x86


    Directory: E:\Software\OpenCV\opencv_winrt\opencv-master\bin\WP\8.0


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         17-Feb-16  11:36 PM            x86
INFO> Generating project:
INFO> cmake -G Visual Studio 12 2013 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:String=WindowsPhone -D
MAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:String=8.0 -DCMAKE_VS_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS:String=x86 -DCMAK
_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=E:\Software\OpenCV\opencv_winrt\opencv-master\bin\install\
P\8.0\x86 E:\Software\OpenCV\opencv_winrt\opencv-master
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (project):
  A Windows Phone component with CMake requires both the Windows Desktop SDK
  as well as the Windows Phone '8.0' SDK.  Please make sure that you have
  both installed


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Software/OpenCV/opencv_winrt/opencv-master/bin/WP/8.0/x86/CMakeFil
s/CMakeOutput.log".
INFO> -----------------------------------------------
INFO> Building and installing project:
INFO> Executing: msbuild OpenCV.sln /p:Configuration='Debug' /m
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.21005.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: OpenCV.sln
INFO> Error: Failure executing command: msbuild OpenCV.sln /p:Configuration='De
ug' /m
```

I have confirmed the Windows SDK installed or not  by looking at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
```

and I can see following directories there,

```
v7.0A,  v7.1A,  v8.0,  v8.0A,  v8.1, v8.1A
```

What could be the issue here?